# xdebug dbgp client for linux

Tags: php, linux, client, xdebug

I'm looking for some type of program that will allow me to do remote debugging PHP on Linux, one that would satisfy these two humble requirements:

1. No thick Java IDE. I want to be able to launch it quickly, or keep it running in the background, ready to be used when needed. I need to use my RAM, not waste it on an iddle debugger.
2. Good learnin curve. Vim works - somehow, but.. I need to concentrate on other things when debugging, not my poor vim-fu and digging through manuals for how to dig through vim manuals, only to figure out how close tab in Vim. I don't like debugging the debugger. I didn't try emacs, I'm sort of scared to do so. I would prefer simple mouse-oriented program, so I can fully concentrate on debugging.

Is there such a program?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of possibilities, there seems to be new plugin for Sublime text. 
Not ready, but looks promising.

https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug